# Open Source Desktop Sharing

Tags: remote-desktop

I 'm looking for Desktop sharing utility that I can use to incorporate inside a small elearning app that I'm building...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try VNC. It's OS agnostic and it works really well. It's been around for many years now and I haven't been able to crash it.

http://www.realvnc.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also have look at teamviewer. I guess its opensource and create secured connection on internet.

Comment: Team Viewer is not open source

Comment: It used to be open source, but that was back in 2006, and the source code isn't too different from VNC's. Look at web.archive.org for TeamViewer's 2006 source code.